# Video streaming, Audio Streaming, Video Recording and Audio Recording in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to implement video streaming, audio streaming in windows phone 8. Similarly, how to implement video and audio recording from media element.

Can we implement above functionality using Windows Phone 8 SDK or need to go with some third party tools.

Thanks,
Prakash.

Comment: _What you have tried so far?_

Comment: I'm just starting with windows phone 8 development. I tried created MediaElement element and assigned path of video file. now, looking for video and audio streaming related tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 provides a rich set of [APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to play [video](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Video_Playback_with_MediaElement_in_Windows_Phone) and audio which includes streaming from a remote service.

You may need a third party library if your files are using a codec that is not supported by the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I tried from that Link, I'm able to achieve video streaming using MediaPlayerLauncher, but not sure how to use options like pause, rewind, forward using MediaPlayerLauncher. Similarly I want to record the video as well as audio of the played video..

Comment: @Prakash a lot of your questions are answered in the official http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402551(v=vs.105).aspx note that recording video is located in the within the camera api http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207006(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll check that link too